# Is there a paint, finish, or coating that will hold up to pet scratching?

Tags: doors, paint

I've repainted my exterior doors four or five times since getting a dog two years ago.
I installed a pet door, but she occasionally scratches the back or side door when she wants to come in or go out.
A couple of weeks of German shepherd claws and the doors look terrible.
I tried oil and water-born enamels, lacquer/automotive paint, and my most recent failure of acrylic paint with a polyurethane topcoat.
Are there door coatings made to withstand this type of abuse?

Comment: The true fix is to modify the dog's behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Metal sheeting is probably your best option, but if you really want a hard coating instead, two-pack also known  as "2K" is probably the best.  There's lots of nasty chemicals in there. Ordinary respirator filters won't protect you, also not recommended for DIY - take you door to a professional.

A step down from 2-pack is polyurethane resin which is the stuff used in fibreglass. VOC but not as bad as 2-Pack.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, brass or aluminium panels work well.

Once the dogs learns then they can be removed.

Much cheaper than replacing doors and frames.